# C# NelderMeadSolver with multidimensional input array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use the `NelderMeadSolver` to implement an optimizer for 2 dimensional double array. However, I noticed that after I declare the delegate as

```
Func<double[,], double> myFuncDelegate = Myfunction
```

where Myfunction takes a 2 dimensional double array, say for example double `[,]` M. Having setting the initial values Mini, lower bound ML and upper bound MU (all are double `[,]`), when I write

```
NelderMeadSolver.Solve(myFuncDelegate,Mini, ML, MU )
```

The compiler will report following errors:

> " cannot convert from 'System.Func' to
>   'System.Func'    " (myFuncDelegate)
>
> " cannot convert from 'double[*,*]' to 'double[]'"  (Mini)
>
> " cannot convert from 'double[*,*]' to 'double[]'"  (ML)
>
> " cannot convert from 'double[*,*]' to 'double[]'"  (MU)

Following is the code:

```
    private static double Myfunction(double[,] M)
    {
        return (100 * Math.Pow(M[0, 0] - Math.Pow(M[0, 1], 2), 2)) + Math.Pow(1 - M[0, 1], 2);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<double[,], double> myFuncDelegate = Myfunction;
        double[,] Mini = new double[,]{{0,1},{1,1}} ;
        double[,] ML = new double[,] { { 0, 1 }, { -1, -1 } };
        double[,] MU = new double[,] { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 } }; ;
        var solution = NelderMeadSolver.Solve(myFuncDelegate, Mini, ML, MU);}
```

Errors occurs for the last statement

Any suggestion to this problem?

Comment: It's better to include code in your question.

Comment: Microsoft Solver Foundation is no longer maintained; Nelder-Mead algorithms typically expect a vector as function argument rather than a matrix; you are supposed to define Decision variables for the solver

Comment: thanks your reminder@AxelKemper. I also noticed Nelder-Mead only takes 1d vector input. I will revise my function input accordingly.

Comment: @Eric if you solved your problem, please answer your own question and let everyone know what you did.

Comment: Instead of adding 'solved' to the title, you can either: (1)write an answer that describes what you found and how did you fix it (you can even 'accept' your own answers after a day or two I think),or (2) mark it as to be "closed" since it is bad/odd/wrong/notneeded/etc (no one will post there, but you can later get it re-opened if you need it for some reason - but often it's better to ask a new question), or (3) mark it as to be 'deleted' instead of just 'closed'

Comment: Thanks for @AxelKemper's reply. I revised the method Myfunction to take an 1d array as its input. This is done by implementing a  method that converts a 2D array into a vector. And now the NelderMeadSolver works.